Polynomial approximation of $1/z$ on the unit circle without $1$
Does there exist a sequence of polynomials that uniformly converges to $1/z$ on $\{z:|z|=1,z\neq 1\}$?
If we work on the unit circle, then by contour integration along the circle we can show that there is no such sequence. With $1$ removed the curved is not closed anymore, so we can't apply things like maximum modulus principle or contour integral. How to proceed on this question?

If $|p(z) - 1/z| \le \epsilon$ on ${z:|z|=1,z\neq 1}$ then the same estimate holds on the entire unit circle ...

to add to what @Martin says, the answer is actually affirmative if you take out any nontrivial arc so you ask the question on $|z| =1, |\arg z| \ge \epsilon >0$
